# Dynamic URL and Sheet using =Importange

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, syntax, reference

I'm trying to make a =ImportRange with a dynamic URL and Sheet, but I'm doing something wrong.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQRDK.png
[image]

I've also tryed with ""=Q24"A3:A3") where Q24 = August-September !, but that also give an error.
I want to do the same thing with the URL, but I also get an error when I try to do that.

Is it possible and if, which command do i need to use.
I hope someone could help me.

Br
Anders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1HeGmCh3fFgHAfJSIsCIFkFi48PWpXR0iZdBcv4HhSWw"; Q24&"!A3")
```